# Gate Mage implementation for D&D or Pathfinder

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, class

Gate mages, described in the Mither Mages series by Orson Scott Card, are potent healers, tricksters, travelers, and linguists. They have some potential as damage dealers in that they can use gates to cut off body parts. Or create two gates so that an arrow can be sent back at the shooter. They can also be fairly hard to kill due to being able to escape and heal.

What they can do in the books makes them gods so they are fairly over powered.

Description from the [Mither Mages Wiki](http://mithermages.wikia.com/wiki/Gatemage)

> A Gatemage was arguably, along with a manmage, the most powerful of all Mither Mages.  A servant of spacetime, a gatemage was able to create a portal, or "gate", that would transport a person or thing instantaneously between two points.  Gates, in addition to being powerful means of travel and manipulation, would heal any wound when a person passes through.
>
> Gatemages also had the power to create Great Gates, which were formed by weaving a dozen or more gates together and extending them from one world to another.  The passage between worlds (Westil and Mittlegard) greatly strengthened any mage's power many fold.  Thus, gatemages were extremely valuable to fellow mages in the quest for greater power. Were forced to be killed because Loki closed all the great gates and if a family could get there hands on one that could make a great gate they could destroy the other families.

How could one implement them (perhaps as a new class) in D&D 5e or Pathfinder? Pointers to past implementations are also welcome.

Comment: D&D 3.5e is far closer to Pathfinder than 5e is, and also has been around for a lot longer and had a more open licensing scheme. So I suggest that you would be more likely to get results, and those results would be more usable, with [[tag:dnd-3.5e]] than [[tag:dnd-5e]]. On the other hand, [[tag:dungeons-and-dragons]] for covering multiple editions might work (though anything from non-3.5e editions are going to be little more than inspiration as far as something workable in Pathfinder goes).

Comment: I at this point where I'm thinking creating the class would be simpler. So it would become more or less how to not make it extremely over powered while not nerfing it into a portal slave.

Comment: Yes, and we can also help with that potentially, though asking that question can be difficult.

Comment: Note that if your comment is what you’re after, this Q&A won’t cover that and you’ll need to post it as a separate question.

Comment: RE: "Were forced to be killed because Loki closed all the great gates and if a family could get there hands on one that could make a great gate they could destroy the other families." This last sentence in the quotation doesn't flow with the rest of the quotation. Is the quotation accurate?

Comment: If you'd like this to have a chance to be reopened, pick one system (PF or 5e). Make that the system for this question.  Then ask the same question for the other system.

Answer (score 1):

## You don't need a class for this.

In Pathfinder, there are items and spells that can duplicate everything you want perfectly fine, though if you had to have a class it would be a summoner archetype.

### Spells

level 2 spells: twisted space

level 4 spells: teleport, dimension door

level 5 spells: astral projection (lesser)

level 6 spells: ice crystal teleport

level 7 spells: greater teleport, walk through space, ethereal jaunt, plane shift

level 9 spells: gate, interplanetary teleport, astral projection, etherealness

As you can see, spells are in abundance!

### Items

Helm of teleportation: fits with the teleportation theme

Ring Gates: this is the most like what you want you can feasibly get, two gates that you *CAN* shoot an arrow through and stick your hand through and... the possibilities are endless

Cubic Gates: Inter-Dimensional travel is possible with this

Bag of Holding: every gate mage should have a handy extra-dimensional space with them for their stuff

All items that replicate teleportation of plane shifting: there are a LOT of these

### Abilities

From the core rule book there is monks abundant step, which is basically dimension door

From (I think) the Advanced Players Guide there is the Flowing Monk's redirect attack, which mimics lots of spells

### Conclusion:

You don't need a new class for this, there isn't already one out there; but with all these items and spells you can make your dream gate mage...

Comment: Where is the ring gate item sourced from? It's not in any of the 5e source books

Comment: @illustro: Given some of the other things the answer mentions, I'm guessing their references all relate to Pathfinder, not 5e.

Comment: its from pathfinder

Comment: i mean all of it; i mainly play pathfinder